# Netplan Static Address for a specific connection otherwise dhcp

Tags: networking, server, raspberrypi, netplan

I am new to Netplan Configuration so please if its a duplicate question, just point me to the right answer since I couldn't find something that matches my problem.

So, I've got a Raspberry pi 4 and installed Ubuntu Server 18.04.4. I enabled wifi following directions from this [site](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/netplan-how-to-configure-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu-18-04-using-netplan.html). I would like to use static IP, so I can successfully SSH to it without huzzles.

But I need to set the static ip for each connection I've got separately and not for the interface. For example at work with SSID "A" it should be 192.168.0.XXX and at home with separate SSID "B" it should 192.168.1.XXX. Is this possible with netplan? How can I accomplish this?

If it's possible for any other SSIDs I would like it to switch to DHCP.

If you want any more information, or you think you need more specific parameters just ask me and I'll provide them.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you that this is not supported today, because address and routing information in netplan is associated with the interface only, and not with the access points.

It is a reasonable thing to want to be able to do through netplan.  Could you file a bug report requesting this at https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan?

Comment: Perhaps there is already a bug reported regarding this?  So i dont file a duplicate one? I am not really sure on how to proceed and report the bug/feature request!  How would one do the expected behaviour then if not with netplan?

Comment: I don't believe there is an existing bug report for this and I am encouraging you to file the bug report because it is always better to have an end user describe their needs in their own words, and get information directly from the developers about the progress on implementation status, than to have another developer proxy this and possibly get it wrong.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help! I will report it hoping for some answers!

Comment: @XenakisKaramanos - Did you end up reporting this as a bug? I am facing the same problem and wanted to see if you ever found a resolution?

Comment: I did report it but none seemed to respond about it. Here is the bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1878168 if you want to pursue further. I just installed Ubuntu if i remember correctly to actually solve my problem.